# Algorithm2e and hanging captions

Tags: captions, algorithm2e

I'm having issues trying to **make the captions in Algorithn2e hang**, as in the table caption pictured below. I plan on using them together with `arsclassica`/`classicthesis`, but it seems neither of these packages affect the issue.

[image]

I have tried using `\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}` and `\captionsetup{format=hang}`, but `algorithm2e` seems not to be affected by them. The `classicthesis` style file seems to be achieving this effect exactly this way. The `algorithm2e` documentation doesn't mention hanging captions and I couldn't find anything (that I would decypher as caption code) in the style file either. Finally, google also didn't yield anything and I am finding myself a little bit out of depth with my latex skills here.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[algoruled]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{classicthesis}
%\usepackage{arsclassica}

% these two lines don't make a difference   
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}   
\captionsetup{format=hang}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[htb]
    \While{true}
    {   
    }
    \caption{Morbi blandit vehicula leo a consectetur. Aliquam a lacus posuere, consectetur tortor at, mollis erat.}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I have been able to format the rest of the `algorithm2e` caption with some trial and error and hacking. I'm only interested in the hanging part of the problem here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[algoruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}   
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

% Un-define ''algorithm'' as defined by the algorithm package
\let\algorithm\relax
\let\endalgorithm\relax
\expandafter\let\csname algorithm*\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endalgorithm*\endcsname\relax
\let\listofalgorithms\relax

% Define the new algorithm environment
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{algorithm}

\makeatletter
% Definition for the style ruled
% First add the rules enclosing the captiom
\DeclareCaptionFormat{algrule}{%
  \rule{\textwidth}{0.8pt}\par
  {\@hangfrom{#1#2}%
     \advance\caption@parindent\hangindent
     \advance\caption@hangindent\hangindent
     \caption@@par#3\par}%
  \vspace*{-8pt}\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-5pt}     
}
% Now add the rules after the algorithm
\AtEndEnvironment{algorithm}{\vspace*{-9pt}\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}

% Apply the new format to the algorithm environment
\captionsetup[algorithm]{format=algrule}

% Settings for the list of algorithms
\let\oldlistofalgorithms\listofalgorithms
\renewcommand\listofalgorithms{
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\algorithmname~}
\oldlistofalgorithms
\clearpage
\endgroup
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\begin{algorithm}[htb]
\caption{Morbi blandit vehicula leo a consectetur. Aliquam a lacus posuere, consectetur tortor at, mollis erat.}
    \While{true}
    {   
    }
\end{algorithm}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\Huge
A
\caption{Morbi blandit vehicula leo a consectetur. Aliquam a lacus posuere, consectetur tortor at, mollis erat.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
\Huge
A
\caption{Morbi blandit vehicula leo a consectetur. Aliquam a lacus posuere, consectetur tortor at, mollis erat.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

An image of the list of algorithms:

[image]

An image of the document showing the new environment in action:

[image]

The `algorithm` environment defined by `algorithm2e` is defined internally using the `float` package, so it's behaviour is not exactly the same as the one for standard floats and the environment is not 100% compatible with some of the features of the `caption` package.

One possible solution is then to un-define the `algorithm` environment defined by the `algorithm2e` package and define a new `algorithm` float with the help of the `newfloat` package. This new environment is fully compatible with the `caption` package, so one can use all the features offered by the package; in particular, settings like the hanging indentation will now apply directly (notice how nicely the new object inherits the settings from `classicthesis`/`arsclassica`).

An `algrule` format was used to imitate the look and feel of the `ruled` style of the original environment. The `\caption` command inside the new `algorithm` environment has to be used *before* the actual algorithm.

The solution also takes care of producing a "List of Algorithms" following the settings of the other standard lists.

The procedure used is, in fact, recommended in the documentation of the `caption` package:

> Note: Only one single caption can be typeset inside environments
>   defined with `\newfloat` or `\restylefloat`, furthermore these
>   environments are not behaving exactly like the pre-defined floats
>   `figure` and `table`. As a consequence many packages do not cooperate
>   well with these.
>
> Furthermore the `float` package has some caveats & limitations, so if
>   you just want to define a new simple floating environment—behaving
>   like figure or table—I recommend using `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment`
>   offered by the `newfloat` package instead.

Comment: You MWE, verbatim as it is, errors out with !LaTeX Error: Command \listofalgorithms already defined. Or name of \end... illegal. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @JanBenes I had forgotten to also un-define the original list. I've fixed the code now.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I'll just remark that the position of the `\caption` statement within the `algorithm` matters, as I just found out. Great answer, much appreciated!

Comment: @JanBenes Ah, you're right. I forgot to mention this in my answer. Will do it right now.

Comment: @JanBenes I updated my answer providing now the proper settings for an eventual "List of Algorithms"; the new information might be of interest for you.

Comment: The list of algorithms is the other issue I was having, but didn't want to ask for solutions to two problems in one questions. Thanks for thinking ahead! :-) (also, an alternative solution has been provided at https://code.google.com/p/classicthesis/issues/detail?id=37)

Comment: Is there also a way of keeping the `algorithm2e` settings for the appearance of the algorithm? The solution seems to be very specific to just one style.